# a doubt on conjugate subgroup in Dummit&Foote's Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

I have a doubt ${\color{red}{\text{(the red part below)}}}$ in Dummit&Foote's Abstract Algebra on page134 :

> **Corollary 14.** If $K$ is any subgroup of the group $G$ and $g\in G$ , then ${\color{red}{K\cong gKg^{-1}}}$ . Conjugate elements and conjugate subgroups have the same order.
>
> *Proof:* ${\color{red}{\text{Letting }G=H}}$ ${\color{red}{\text{ in the proposition shows that}}}$ ${\color{red}{\text{conjugation by }g\in G}}$ ${\color{red}{\text{ is an automorphism of }G\ ,}}$ from which the corollary follows.

And the proposition in the above paragraph is:

> **Proposition 13.** Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of the group $G$ . Then $G$ acts by conjugation on $H$ as automorphisms of $H$ . More specifically, the action of $G$ on H by
> conjugation is defined for each $g\in G$ by
> $$
> h\mapsto ghg^{-1}\ \ \text{for each }h\in H\ .
> $$
> For each $g\in G$ , conjugation by $g$ is an automorphism of $H$ . The permutation representation afforded by this action is a homomorphism of $G$ into  with kernel $C_G(H)$ . In particular, $G/C_G(H)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(H)$ .

What I can know is just that letting $G=H$ in proposition13 we obtain $G=gGg^{-1}$ , but how can it ${\color{red}{\text{(the sentence in red)}}}$ conclude that $K\cong gKg^{-1}$ ? I could not find the connection with them although it is easy to check that $K\cong gKg^{-1}$ is true in other ways.

Answer (score 1):

Proposition 13, applied with $G = H$, tells you that the function $$\phi : G \to G, \ \ \ \ \ \phi(x) = g x g^{-1}$$
is an *isomorphism*, for any $g \in G$.

Restricting $\phi$ to the subgroup $K \subset G$, we obtain an isomorphism
$$ \phi|_K : K \to \phi(K), \ \ \ \ \ \phi(x) = g x g^{-1}. $$

The image $\phi(K)$ is precisely $gKg^{-1}$. Thus $K$ is isomorphic to $gKg^{-1}$, via the isomorphism $x \mapsto gxg^{-1}$.

Comment: I get it, thanks!